# Map annotation title not showing in iOS 7.0 but showing in 6.0 and 7.1

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit

Hey i am working on a map based iOS app, in iOS 6.0 and 7.1 the map showing the annotation title but not in 7.0 . Please tell is there any dependency that affect so. I am using a custom map annotation view for the annotations. The viewForAnnotation shows that the annotation has the title but is not displaying. Why?? please tell me.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
CusomeMapAnnotation *customMap = (CusomeMapAnnotation *)annotation;
CustomMapAnnotationView *pinAnnot = (CustomMapAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"Location"];
if (!pinAnnot) {
    pinAnnot = [[CustomMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:customMap reuseIdentifier:@"Location"];
}
switch (customMap.bck_type) {
    case 0:
        pinAnnot.playMapPin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"play_NP_button.png"];
        pinAnnot.playMapPin.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:54.0/255.0 green:208.0/255.0 blue:120.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        break;
    case 1:
        pinAnnot.playMapPin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"play_city_button.png"];
        pinAnnot.playMapPin.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:191.0/255.0 green:83.0/255.0 blue:161.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        break;
    case 2:
        pinAnnot.playMapPin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"play_water_button.png"];
        pinAnnot.playMapPin.color = [UIColor colorWithRed: 39.0/255.0 green:169.0/255.0 blue:193.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
pinAnnot.title=customMap.placeTitle;
if ([self isVideoAlreadySaved:customMap.videoFile])
{
    pinAnnot.playMapPin.progress = 1.0;
}

NSMutableDictionary *tempData;
for(int i=0;i<appDelegate.downloadQueue.count;i++)
{
    tempData=[appDelegate.downloadQueue objectAtIndex:i];
    if([[tempData objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue]==customMap.coordinate.latitude&&[[tempData objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue]==customMap.coordinate.longitude)
        pinAnnot.playMapPin.progress=[[tempData objectForKey:@"Progress"] doubleValue]/100;
}
pinAnnot.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,200,150);
pinAnnot.playMapPin.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeScale (customMap.scale, customMap.scale);
pinAnnot.canShowCallout = NO;
if (customMap.scale<0.25) {
    [pinAnnot bringSubviewToFront:[mapView.subviews lastObject]];
}
[pinAnnot setNeedsDisplay];
return pinAnnot;
```

}

pinAnnot shows that it has the value for title but it is not displayed on map.

for customMap Annotation in .h i have

```
@interface CustomMapAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView{
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) CusomeMapAnnotation *customMap;
@property (nonatomic, strong) STKSpinnerView *playMapPin;
@property (nonatomic ,strong) NSString *title;
-(void)needsLayoutWithZoomLevel:(int)zoomLevel;
@end
```

and in .m

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    NSMutableAttributedString *finalAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_title];

```
[finalAttributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, finalAttributedString.length)];

[finalAttributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontsize+((map_zoomLevel-4)*1.2)] range:NSMakeRange(0, finalAttributedString.length)];

[finalAttributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, finalAttributedString.length)];

[finalAttributedString addAttribute:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-3.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, finalAttributedString.length)];

[finalAttributedString addAttribute:NSStrokeColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, finalAttributedString.length)];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *mutParaStyle=[[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[mutParaStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[finalAttributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:mutParaStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, finalAttributedString.length)];

[finalAttributedString drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,_playMapPin.frame.origin.y+_playMapPin.frame.size.height+1, 200, 100)];


_playMapPin.wellThickness = 5.0;
[_playMapPin setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self addSubview:_playMapPin];
```

}

images of iOS 6 and iOS 7 showing the problem.

[image: iOS 6]

[image]

Note that the text is displayed using NSAttributedString.

Comment: you need to post code before you ask what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Question updated. Please have a look at it.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with it, working fine in ios 6.0 and 7.1.

Comment: How is your CustomMapAnnotationView defined?

Comment: customMapAnnotation has drawRect as added in the code.

Comment: I think it will not be possible to understand the whole code, so please tell me what is the differences in map view in 7.0 from 6.0 and 7.1.

Comment: Problem solved, is was due to the use of NSMutableAttributedString, i used UILabel instead of it and added the label's text with the same attributes that the NSMutableAttributedString object had.